# Does the concept of slang exist in cultures without established written or formal education traditions?

Tags: english, language-change, written-language, spoken-language, slang

In English and, presumably, many of the world's other commonly spoken languages, there exists a rough category of words considered slang. This concept is not quite the same as taboo (many slang words are not really related to taboo topics), colloquial language (I think that a number of colloquial lexical items, like "yeah," could not be reasonably classified as slang), new/youth words (COVID is obviously not slang; on the other hand, some slang terms are quite old).

I feel that standardized writing plays a role in the concept. Slang words are ones which are significantly less common in formal writing than in everyday speech. However, this also applies to non-slang colloquial words and linguistic features.

Formal education also seems to play a role. Educators use colloquial words and newer features of their language often (One of my teachers said "your guys's" at least half a dozen times when explaining the instructions for the SAT), but they are unlikely to utilize slang terms very much. Speakers learn these words in other places.

Because of these factors, I am wondering whether a concept of "slang words" exists in cultures whose languages don't have significant written traditions and aren't taught in any formal education system. Do such cultures recognize certain words as slang? Is the concept as prominent in these cultures as it is in the Anglosphere?

Comment: Every culture has various registers of speech. There's nothing that truly separates slang from other words, it's just what gets used in the less formal registers

Comment: Slang is used usually to hide bad "concepts" behind beautiful words, even when proper words exist for the "bad" things. Please remember that originally "pussy" meant "cat". So any society which has a language and has some emotions associated to good or bad, will develop some type of slang. Probably, the only place in the universe where slang is unlikely is planet Vulcan (reference to the Star Trek series, home planet of Mr. Spock) - where people train to NOT have feelings / emotions, just reason.

Comment: @virolino there's plenty of slang for neutral or positive topics e.g. "cool". The main thing is as curiousdanii says, that it's used in less formal registers and so tends to deal with less formal topics - some of those are "bad", but plenty of things are not

Comment: @Tristan: you are right, there are several "kinds" of slang. But as a minimum, there is the slang I explained above. Now the interesting thing is if they have the concept of "slang" itself (additional to the words themselves) - which is the object of the question.

Comment: @virolino sure, some slang is euphemism, but not all slang is euphemism, and not all euphemism is slang, so I'm not sure arguing that euphemism is universal is a helpful line of reasoning

Comment: @Tristan: now you insist to make me start thinking? :)) Good point, to consider euphemisms in the discussion. Tnx.

Comment: There are probably some Amerindian languages and suchlike without much slang. I think that slang is connected to cities and economic development (classes).

Comment: @Lambie Yep, socioeconomic classes and urban centers definitely have a huge impact on slang. I was also wondering if cultures without those have the concept of slang, but that seems like a topic for a separate question.

Comment: There are a **lot** of ways that what we call _slang_ can be part of culture. Take a look at Sapirs ["Abnormal Types of Speech in Nootka"](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=inu.30000087080705&view=1up&seq=7) to see a few. And bear in mind that this situation was the norm for hunter/gatherer cultures for the first 90% of the life of human language.

Comment: Anyone interested in registers in Amerind languages should read [Sapir's classic paper on "Abnormal Types of Speech in Nootka"](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=inu.30000087080705&view=1up&seq=7). It's simply amazing how much free time for language play hunting/gathering cultures have. It's almost as complex as Australian mother-in-law languages.

Answer (score -1):

Now, if I may, the opposite is quite possible, too, that is, a language that is mostly written and has therefore no slang. Italian is historically the learned language of Italy, it has been so for many centuries: that means that in everyday conversations people in Italy use their native language/dialect. Italian being almost only a written or learned language, it means there's no informal version of it. That is especially remarkable in dubbed medias, when they try to invent Italian slang versions of (usually) American slang words, for example, when in movies they try to translate "cool" into Italian. Whatever they come up with sounds extremely weird and contrieved...

Comment: While it was undoubtedly true that people in Italy used to speak the local language in their homes, this has become less and less common and varies geographically (e.g. there are regional languages that are high prestige, and others that are low prestige). If I recall correctly the amount of speakers using standard Italian in informal contexts has passed 50% in the early 2000s and grown up quite quickly from there. And Italian slang is absolutely a thing, although it's not homogeneous either geographically or temporally (but what slang is?).

Comment: Denis, regional differences are definitely a thing, you're right, but I was thinking particularly about movie dubbing, and about how awkward it sounds when they try and find a way to translate into Italian American slang words or expressions, even very common words like "cool": they usually resort to dialect words that make it uncomprehensible to Italians who don't speak that specific dialect, or make something up, which usually sounds comical or weird.. .

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with a perceived lack of slang, and more with the difficulty of translations in general, and of movie dubs in particular (they have additional constraints like matching the words to lip movements). As to the example of the word *cool* it is true that it has no equivalent in contemporary slang - people use *figo* but it is significantly more informal than *cool* - but if you go to the 80s there were the perfect translations *ganzo* or *togo* (now extremely out of date).